# Drag and Drop with Submit that will show all the drop() data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

So I'm trying to do a drag and drop system wherein I can pick from 40 images and drop them to another 6 blank div. The images has their own id as numbers like id="1". Like 1-40 also. I can only choose 6 out of 40 and then print or alert those 6 random numbers that I've got. I'm using those JS below and they're perfectly fine:

```
function allowDrop(ev)
{
document.getElementById(ev.target.id).innerHTML = "";
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
var new_img = $('#'+data).clone();
$('#'+ev.target.id).html(new_img);
alert(data)

}
```

The problem is my submit() function. I just want to get all 6 numbers from the images that I've dropped in the 6 blank divs and display them. I just don't know what's wrong with the submit() function that I've made. Am I not getting the data from where I dropped them? Please help, Thank you!

```
function submit() {


  var guess=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var guess2 = guess+boxes[i].innerHTML;
            if (guess2.length >= 6 && guess2.length <= 12){
              alert(guess)
            }
}
```

Comment: For one, `id`s can't only be a number, [an `id` has to start with a letter](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id). Try this: `<element id="img_1">`. To extract number: `var id = parseInt(ev.target.id.substring(ev.target.id.indexOf("_")+1));` *(if you only need the number as text, you can leave out the `parseInt()`)*

Comment: When does submit() run?

Comment: Hi novice, submit() run during onclick on a button